# Rxjs operator delay doesn't delay the emitted values from of

Tags: rxjs

I would like to emit a value every second. So I created the following code:

```
of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
   .pipe(map(val => val + 10), delay(1000))
   .subscribe(console.log);
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8macjg?devtoolsheight=60)

But this code still prints all the values at once with an initial delay of 1 second. But how can you delay every value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `RxJS` `interval` function like the following:

```js
interval(1000)
    .pipe(map((val) => val + 10))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```